# Get statistics shared mail Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I need to get all messages with labels to do statistics. I have a cuestion, because when I execute with my email I don't have any problem but the goal is getting statistics of shared account of gmail. For example, if I've used the next script:

```
    /**
    * Lists the labels in the user's account.
    */
    function listLabels() {
      var response =  Gmail.Users.Labels.list('test@company.com');
    if (response.labels.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
    Logger.log('Labels:');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = response.labels[i];
      Logger.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
     }
   }
```

Where test@company.com is my shared account and I'm always getting a denied. I'm not sure if a problem with shared company or the method for logging is incorrect. The fact, If I do a logging with my shared email, really I see my personal account.

Thanks for your help.

Update with new code (JSON data are fake):

```
var JSON = {
    "private_key": "xxxx",
    "client_email": "mail_shared@test.com",
    "client_id": "client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "user_email": "personal@test.com"
};

function getOAuthService(user) {
    return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
        .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
        .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
        .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
        .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels');
}

function reset() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
}

/**
    * Lists the labels in the user's account.
    */
    function listLabels() {
      var service = getOAuthService();
      service.reset();

    var response = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('mail_shared@test.com');
    if (response.labels.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
    Logger.log('Labels:');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = response.labels[i];
      Logger.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
     }
   }
```

I've tried the next differents scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels

Comment: The implementation for this would be tricky, try using service account as suggested by this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script). Though it is a shared account, this is still considered as a different account aside from your authenticated user. That said, domain-wide delegation would work for you.

Comment: The Oauth2 works fine,I think, but I'm getting the same error. But, I think the problem is a bad use of OAut. The new code is in the question.